# Cygwin fatal error: is not a directory

Tags: cygwin, to-do

I'm trying to use [todotxt](http://todotxt.com/) in Cygwin on Windows 7. However, when I do `t add "test"` I get an error message: `"Fatal Error: $/cygdrive/c/Users/Travis/todo is not a directory"`. However,  `cd /cygdrive/c/Users/Travis/todo"` works just fine:

[image]

Edit: in my .bashrc file, I have the following: `alias t="/cygdrive/c/users/Travis/todo/todo.sh"`. Additionally, executing `/cygdrive/c/users/travis/todo/todo.sh add "test"` from the shell fails with the same error message, even though `cd /cygdrive/c/users/travis/todo` works perfectly well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two different paths. The one you configured todo.txt to use has an extra `$` at the beginning.

Comment: I think Cygwin is adding that somehow. In my .bashrc file I have: alias t="/cygdrive/c/users/Travis/todo/todo.sh", and the following produces the same error when executed from the shell: /cygdrive/c/users/travis/todo/todo.sh add "test"

Comment: What `TODO_DIR` is set in your `todo.cfg`?

Comment: And there was the problem: the relevant line did have the $ at the beginning: export TODO_DIR=`dirname "$/cygdrive/c/Users/Travis/todo/todo.txt"`. I changed that and it works now.